# Set a different media type for 401 error code using Swashbuckle

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Is it possible to configure Swashbuckle to produce a different media type for a specific HTTP error code 401 in Swagger UI?

[image]

I want the media type for the 400 error code to be application/JSON, but for 401, it is text/HTML. Is there a way to achieve this?

Annotations above controller,

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

Annotations above my method,

```
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<MyModel>> PostAsync(MyRequest myRequest)
    {
}
```

Comment: Do you write the OpenAPI file manually or generate it from code? If the latter - what language and library do you use?

Comment: Latter, and C# and Swagger.

Comment: What library do you use - Swashbuckle, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, Swagger-Net, NSwag, something else? Also post your current annotations for 4xx responses.

Comment: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, Updated my question with annotations.

Comment: and you want to change this only for swaggerUI ? when some app calls your API then in that case which media type you want ?

Comment: Yeah, just for SwaggerUI, when a client calls, I am using Windows Authentication, so the client would get an Authentication error.

Comment: @Helen Is there a way to do this using Swashbuckle.Core library?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SwaggerResponse attribute, it derives from ProducesResponseType and has been enhanced to support adding the content media type:

```cs
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status201Created, "Successfully created something", typeof(MyModel), "application/json")]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, "Unauthorized", typeof(string), "text/html")]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, "Invalid request", typeof(string), "text/html")]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Internal Server Error", typeof(string), "text/html")]
```

It is part of the nuget package: `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations`